# Openapi 3.0 mix type array and ref

Tags: swagger, openapi

The doc says we can use `oneOf` under array for mixed types and arrays

```
type: array
items:
    oneOf:
        - type: integer
        - type: string
```

or

```
type: array
items:
    oneOf:
        - $ref: "#/components/object1"
        - $ref: "#/components/object2"
```

I need to have an array with a mix of type and ref like so:

```
type: array
items:
    oneOf:
        - type: integer
        - $ref: "#/components/object2"
```

The documentation doesn't say anything about this, and I can't seem to make the validation work. Is it not supported? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The [Spectral](https://stoplight.io/open-source/spectral) linter doesn't complain about your last code block. The [Redocly Linter](https://redocly.com/docs/cli/commands/lint/) also says: `Woohoo! Your OpenAPI definition is valid.` What validator fails for you and which validation message do you receive from it?

Comment: All of your examples are correct, except the $refs should be `#/components/schemas/object2`. What is the problem you're seeing?

Comment: I'm using [Swagger model validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-model-validator) to validate a JSON object. Somehow, the validator can not catch the case where content of the array is not an integer or the object. I've read through the docs, and it says that: `Any sibling elements of a $ref are ignored. This is because $ref works by replacing itself and everything on its level with the definition it is pointing at.` Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: In your case there is no sibling element of a `$ref`. BTW, please also put additional information into question.

Comment: This seems to be a bug/limitation of `swagger-model-validator`. You can open an issue here: https://github.com/swagger-model-validator/swagger-model-validator/issues